# Unable to create dashboard report via command line

Tags: csv, datetime, jmeter

When I tried the below command lines, in both cases it's not creating dashboard and throws error stating that either csv doesn't exist or not readable. But when I looked into the results folder csv file has generated.

```
#1
jmeter -q version.properties -JcsvFile=C:\JMETER\PROJECT_ST_FINIEX\1XTest.csv -Jthreads=1 -Jrampup=1 -Jduration=1 -Jrampdown=1 -n -t C:\JMETER\PROJECT_ST_FINIEX\ST_Fenix_perf_test.jmx -l C:\JMETER\PROJECT_ST_FINIEX\1Xresults_${__timeShift(MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss,,,,)}\1Xresults.csv -e -o C:\JMETER\PROJECT_ST_FINIEX\Dashboard1Xresults_${__timeShift(MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss,,,,)

Tidying up ...    @ Wed Dec 05 11:46:35 PST 2018 (1544039195541)
Error generating the report: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: C:\JMETER\PROJECT_ST_FINIEX\1Xresults_${__timeShift(MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss,,,,)}\1Xresults.csv does not exist or is not readable


#2
jmeter -q version.properties -JcsvFile=C:\JMETER\PROJECT_ST_FINIEX\1XTest.csv -Jthreads=1 -Jrampup=1 -Jduration=1 -Jrampdown=1 -n -t C:\JMETER\PROJECT_ST_FINIEX\ST_Fenix_perf_test.jmx -l C:\JMETER\PROJECT_ST_FINIEX\Dashboard1Xresults_${__timeShift(MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss,,,,)}\1Xresults.csv -e -o C:\JMETER\PROJECT_ST_FINIEX\Dashboard1Xresults_${__timeShift(MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss,,,,)
```

I would like to have csv and dashboard in single folder if possible i.e #2 otherwise I would like to go with #1. I am not sure what went wrong in #1 and #2

When I tried the third command below, it's successfully creating the dashboard, but folder name is not created using date format

```
#3
jmeter -q version.properties -JcsvFile=C:\JMETER\PROJECT_ST_FINIEX\1XTest.csv -Jthreads=1 -Jrampup=1 -Jduration=1 -Jrampdown=1 -n -t C:\JMETER\PROJECT_ST_FINIEX\ST_Fenix_perf_test.jmx -l C:\JMETER\PROJECT_ST_FINIEX\1Xresults.csv -e -o C:\JMETER\PROJECT_ST_FINIEX\Dashboard1Xresults_${__timeShift(MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm-ss,,,,)}
```

[image]

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [__timeShift()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) is **internal** JMeter function, it will not work from the command shell, you need to go for [`date`](https://ss64.com/nt/date.html) and [`time`](https://ss64.com/nt/time.html) commands instead like

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l "%date:~-4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%.jtl" -e -o "results%date:~-4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%"
   ```
2. You cannot have .jtl file and the dashboard at the same folder as the dashboard folder must be empty so consider providing different locations for them

References:

- [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)
- [Generating Report Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri !It worked! , but the dashboard and results folders are created under the bin folder . When i tried with same date format by specifying the location it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

[__timeShift](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) function is a JMeter function that works inside JMeter , you're using it from command line so it cannot work.

To manipulate dates from command line, just use regular shell commands